# Text outside Input, Angular 4, Microsoft Edge

Tags: angular, input, microsoft-edge, angular-routing, angular-material2

I have got a problem with one thing. I was trying to fix about two hours. So, problem is referred to Microsoft Edge and Input. I am using Angular 4 for my web app. I put an Input field on the page Users. I use routing in my app, so, this page is in the subpage like

```
<app-root>
    <dashboard>
        <users>
            <input> <!-- Input with problem -->
        </users>
    </dashboard>
</app-root>
```

I was debugging, and I found that typed text appears outside app router!!! Not in the INPUT field!
Like

```
TYPED TEXT APPEARS HERE
<app-root>
    <dashboard>
        <users>
            <input> <!-- Input with problem -->
        </users>
    </dashboard>
</app-root>
```

Here is screenshot:
[You can see test at the top, that is needed to be in input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rT9c.jpg)

Help me, please! I hate this browser so much!

P.S. Don't tell me about styles, they are all clear!

Comment: If you hate this browser, why don't you just install Google Chrome (or some other browser)? :)

Comment: Well, I need to do crossbrowser work. So, that why I really need to fix that problem...